# FQL Querying friendlists getting error

Tags: facebook

hope you can help me with something:

I'm executing an fql query to read out users' friendlists.
These users have authed my app, which included the 'read.friendlists'.

Even though it shows my own entire friendlist, for users who aren't friends of min (but have authed the app), it displays the error:

"Can't lookup all friends of USER_ID. Can only lookup for the logged in user or the logged in user's friends that are users of your app."

It's crucial for this app to get the information on friends of the user.

I know the error says it's not possible, but not even when they permitted the app to do so?
My question is: Is it even possible getting a list of friends from the users of my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Can't lookup all friends of USER_ID. Can only lookup for the logged in user or the logged in user's friends that are users of your app."**

Please check your FQL query. This error is saying that in your query you specified a user ID that is NOT the ID of the user currently using the app. However, the user ID you specify in the query should be the same as the user ID when querying the Graph for **/me**.